# Check if user is already liking this facebook page

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

i'm using the following code to create a facebook widget on my webpage.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(){alert('user liked the page');});
FB.init({
  appId      : 'my app-id here',
  xfbml      : true,
  version    : 'v2.3'
});
};
(function(d, s, id){
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

This is working as intended. What i want to do now is check if the user is already liking the page. If so call a function. I tried to use the FB.api function but couldnt get it working. Anyone that has any experience with this?

Comment: You can't. Like-gating is not allowed by Facebook Platform Policy

Comment: Also, the "user_likes" permission will not be granted for your use case. This was announced in the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog